# are unicode characters u+80 - u+BF valid?

Tags: unicode-string

from [Code Point Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

```
Code point <-> UTF-8 conversion First code point    Last code point     Byte 1  Byte 2  Byte 3  Byte 4
U+0000  U+007F  0xxxxxxx    
U+0080  U+07FF  110xxxxx    10xxxxxx    
U+0800  U+FFFF  1110xxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx    
U+10000     [nb 2]U+10FFFF  11110xxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

The table is not clear because u+80 binary is 10000000b, which would be invalid (does not start with 110b). I would think to produce that it would be 0xc280?

I was under the impression that u+80 - u+bf were all invalid start sequences. However, unicode tables state they are valid code points reserved for one byte control characters.

Could anyone out there clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing Unicode code points with their representation in UTF-8.

The Unicode code point  U+0080 is represented in UTF-8 by a two-byte sequence, 11000010 10000000 in binary, C2 80 in hex.

(Note we do not write U+xx for the individual bytes of UTF-8).

What this

```
U+0080  U+07FF  110xxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

is telling you is that for code points in the range 0080 to 07FF, the 11 significant bits are distributed over the 11 'x' places in the two bytes of the equivalent UTF-8 value.